# How to prevent Java navigate in nested exception

Tags: java, exception

In the nested exception in Java the nested Exception is always goes to the parent one so it happens twice and the code below the initial exception is gonna
never be executed.
How to prevent it like in C#?

```
try
{
    try
    {

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Excep  goes to parent Exception try catch
    }        

    The code here is never executes

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: // Excep  goes to parent Exception try catch - Are you throwing the Exception again in inner catch or handling it?

Comment: @Learner Yes the exception happens twice in this model.

Comment: Not sure what you want here, maybe `finally`. Could you elaborate a little and post more realistic code to illustrate what you want/what you have

Comment: @RC. Not `finally`. Just check C# behavior of this case and you will get what I am asking.

Answer (score -1):

Can this solve your problem：
   try
   {
      try
      {

```
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
      // Excep  goes to parent Exception try catch
  }        
  finally
  {
        The code here is never executes
   }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Sorry. It doesnt. In C# if we handle exception it does not affect code belowe `catch{}`.  And it does not provocate second exception.  Has Java the same thing?

Comment: If you don't throw exception in inner catch, it does not affect below code and it does not also provocate second catch.

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer the same as java